# get ViewSet and http_method_names from drf url namespace

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this snippet to construct API URLs using `SimpeRouter()`. In the `urlpatterns` I have declared a namespace called `my_api`, is there a way to get all the associated ViewSets and their respective `http_method` properties?

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from apps.dir.api.views import (
    ViewSet1,
    ViewSet2,
    ViewSet3,
)

router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register("set1", ViewSet1)
router.register("set2", ViewSet2)
router.register("set3", ViewSet3)

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/v1/", include((router.urls, "api_all_sets"), namespace="my_api")),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this using the code below. Works as expected.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from django.urls import URLResolver

def viewset_actions(url_resolvers: URLResolver):
    class_methods = defaultdict(list)
    url_resolver = url_resolvers.namespace_dict
    for resolver in url_resolver.items():
        if "api" in resolver[0]:
            resolve = resolver[1][1]
            for view_path in resolve._callback_strs:
                module_path, class_name = view_path.rsplit(".", 1)
                module = __import__(module_path, fromlist=[class_name])
                viewset_class = getattr(module, class_name)
                model = viewset_class.queryset.model
                app_name = (model.__module__).split(".")[1]
                class_methods[app_name].append(
                    (
                        model._meta.verbose_name,
                        viewset_class.http_method_names,
                    )
                )
    _ordered = dict(sorted(dict(class_methods).items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0]))
    return _ordered
```